# Get picture I take with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, image

I'm trying to do my 1st iOS application, and I'm having some problems with obtaining the picture I just take.

Here are my methods :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //add imagePicker
    _imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imgPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    _imgPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    _imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    _imgPicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _imgPicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    _imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

    //add overlay on imagePicker
    _imageSilhouette.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_pose.image];
    _imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = _imageSilhouette;
    [_vImagePreview addSubview:_imgPicker.view];
}
```

When I click on a button, I have a timer, and after 10seconds, I take the picture :

```
- (void)decreaseTimerCount
{
    _lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", --_timerCount];
    if(_timerCount==0)
    {
        [self takePicture];
    }
}
-(void) takePicture{
    [_timer invalidate];
    [_imgPicker takePicture];
}
```

As I saw in Apple documentation, I added the delegate :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _imageSilhouette.image = img;
    _imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = _imageSilhouette;
    //[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But I don't really understand if I have to declare the imagePickerController somewhere..

I don't understand neither if img does contain the picture I just took ?

Could I please have some help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're not setting the picker's delegate

In the code where you are setting up the image picker, you need to add this:

```
_imgPicker.delegate = self;
```

Also, in the `.h` file for the file where you are making the picker, you need to add the code between the `<>`'s

```
@interface SomeClass:NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Instead of adding the protocol in the .h file, you have the (better) option of adding in the .m file. Doing so avoids telling the world that your class makes use of an image picker:

```
@interface SomeClass () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Add this just before the corresponding `@implementation` line.

Comment: Instead of adding the protocol to the `@interface` in the .h file, you should add it to a class extension in the .m file.

Comment: @rmaddy Really? How do you do that? Feel free to edit my answer and teach both me *and* the OP!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, but the 2lines you make me add are sending me some errors : for `_imgPicker.delegate = self;` it says that I can't assign  incompatible types (self seems to be my class name "SilhouetteViewCtrl" instead of UIImagePickerController). For the 2nd, when I write : `@interface SilhouetteViewCtrl : BaseViewCtrl <UIImagePickerDelegate>`, it doesn't work, but works with : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Comment: @angelos Use UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. Answering question on iPad - I don't have access to a compiler. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Everything works now, even if the picture is reversed and I don't know why :).